# Add whatsapp sticker pack into whatsapp default library which is accessible to public

Tags: whatsapp-stickers

I would like to add/import a sticker pack to Whatsapp without the need to use a third party app on android. Generate a sticker pack file and have it interpreted by whatsapp as if it had been imported from an app.

My final goal is to allow any whatsapp user to use my pack of whatsapp stickers for free.

I am from Singapore, with an organisation that teaches pre-school. We have a brand refresh launch and we wish to share our new logos to the public for free.

Tried all ways to import stickers to whatsapp main library but not able to.